# How to display collection of items as a wrap panel with strictly two columns?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observable collection of some items and I want to display it in wrap panel in the way it would have exactly two columns.

For example, if I have 5 items in collection the first, second and third would stay in the first column and the fourth and the fifth would stay in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you particularly want the items to be able to wrap, then you have no option other than to create your own custom `Panel`.

You can find help with this from the following pages:

- [How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) on WPF Tutorial.NET
- [Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF) on CODE Project

If it does not matter if the objects can wrap or not, you might be able to use a `UniformGrid`. You can find help with this in the [Understanding Uniform Grid control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6197646) post here on Stack Overflow.